# SSH tunnel in Putty says "address already in use" but that's not true

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I've configured a putty session from Lubuntu to a VPS on the Internet via a proxy server. The connection to the VPS is correctly established, but the tunnel isn't.

This is the tunnel configuration:

```
L1446 xx.xx.org:446
```

Before running putty:

```
$ netstat -na | grep 446
$ (No answer)
```

Whe I run putty, I get this log:

```
Event Log: Local port 1446 forwarding to xx.xx.org:446 failed. The address is already in use
```

But:

```
$ netstat -na | grep 446
$ (No answer)
```

So, I don't know where else to check. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to local port (1446), not to the remote address/port.

Try to select another local port in PuTTY tunnel configuation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the error refers to the local port; the "netstat -na | grep 446" was executed in the local machine. I tried other ports (my first try was 446, then 10446, but they all fail). I'm launching putty as gksudo putty in case it was a question with permissions, but... that fails too.